# Count subtasks of a task recursively

Tags: c#, recursion

How could I count the subtasks of a task and count how many of them are done? Any subtask can have many subtasks and we should count the subtasks of the task on the lowest level only (has no more subtasks). (A task is ready when all its subtasks are done. But this is explanation only, all tasks know whether they are ready or not)

```
Task1             (not done)
  SubTask1a        (not done)
     SubTask1a_1  (done)       <-- lowest level
     SubTask1a_2  (not done)   <-- lowest level
  SubTask1b       (not done)   <-- lowest level
```

So in this example Task1 has 3 SubTasks and only one is done.

I managed to iterate the required items, but cannot count sum of subtasks and how many of them are done.

```
var tasks = new List<Task>()
            {
                new Goal(){ Id=1, Name="Task1" ,ParentId=0, Done=false},
                new Goal(){ Id=2, Name="SubTask1a" ,ParentId=1, Done=false},
                new Goal(){ Id=3, Name="SubTask1a_1" ,ParentId=2, Done=true},
                new Goal(){ Id=4, Name="SubTask1a_2" ,ParentId=2, Done=false},
                new Goal(){ Id=5, Name="SubTask1b" ,ParentId=1, Done=false},
            };
Walk(1);

void Walk(int Id)
{
  var children = goals.Where(c => c.ParentId.Equals(Id)).ToList();
  foreach (var item in children)
  {
    Walk(item.Id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
  bool Done(Goal goal)
  {
    var children = goals.Where(c => c.ParentId.Equals(goal.Id)).ToList();
    if (children.Count == 0)
    {
      return goal.Done;
    }
    else
    {
      int itemCount = 0;
      int doneCount = 0;
      foreach (var item in children)
      {
        itemCount++;
        if (Done(item))
          doneCount++;
      }
      return (doneCount == itemCount);
    }
  }
```

?

Answer (score 0):

This solution will give you the amount of pending and done lowest level goals for each goal in the goals list. More comments are in the code.

```
// Helper class that will contain the number of lowest level goals that are either done or pending.
class Status
{
    public int Done { get; set; }
    public int Pending { get; set; }
}

var statuses = new Dictionary<int, Status>();
Walk(goals);
// Now statuses will contain an entry for each goal. And each status will containthe amount of lowest level goals that still need to be completed to complete that goal.

void Walk(IEnumerable<Goal> goals)
{
    foreach (var goal in goals)
    {
        Walk(child);
    }
}

void Walk(Goal goal)
{
    if (statuses.TryGetValue(goal.Id, out Status status)
    {
        // Already walked this goal.
        return;
    }

    var status = new Status();
    var children = goals.Where(c => c.ParentId.Equals(Id)).ToList();
    if (children.Count == 0)
    {
        // This is a lowest level goal. Create a done or pending status.
        status.Done = goal.Done ? 1 : 0;
        status.Pending = status.Done ? 0 : 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // Make sure we've got the statuses of all children.
        Walk(children);
        var childrenIds = children.Select(c => c.Id).ToList();
        foreach (var childStatus in statuses.Where(s => childrenIds.Contains(s.Key))
        {
            // Update the current status with the children's statuses
            status.Done += childStatus.Done;
            status.Pending += childStatus.Pending;
        }
    }

    statuses.Add(goal.Id, status);
}
```